# Detemine details of cdata type

Tags: lua, luajit

In lua (specifically luajit), if a char* is returned from a call to an ffi function, and you were to use the `print` function on the value returned from that function, you will get a string representation like the following:

e.g.

```
cdata<const char *>: 0x7fec343ee8d0
```

On the C side, I'm only able as far as I'm aware to see the type with a call to lua_type which gives me "cdata".

Is there any way to see on the C side how lua represents that, i.e. the type of cdata?

Note: Although I'm using luajit, this piece of legacy code is not using ffi.

Comment: In Lua for lua.org, `lua_type` never gives "cdata".

Comment: _"this piece of legacy code is not using ffi."_ Apparently it is; `cdata` is an FFI type. To directly answer your question, LuaJIT intentionally does not expose cdata operations to the Lua C API.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo - It's not using luajit ffi, it's using the traditional lua C api.

Comment: Thinking about it, I don't think it is possible.  Because in C you can't get the type of an object at run time since anything can really be anything.  Even if it is half passed through the luajit internals.  ah well.